# What is the right way to connect google fonts with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack-2

There are multiple ways to connect google font.

- Inside index.html template
- Inside scss using css @import directive
- Might it could be done with require + any special loader
- Using special plugin ***google-fonts-webpack-plugin***
- Any other way?

I would say that the best way is to connect font using require + any special loader because it's similar to any other scss addition to the project.

I don't like connecting the google fonts ***google-fonts-webpack-plugin*** because you add something what should be rather in css or html to webpack config.